# Can't find a product by SKU

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

I have some problem with admin panel product search. The products in some categories can't be found by SKU, only by name, while the others can. I've tried to search with `SKU:`, but that didn't change anything. WordPress v5.1.1, WooCommerce v3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

**Add This Code In functions.php then save it.**

> After Changes, You can see the changes in the screenshots

[image]

[image]

```
function search_by_sku_for_admin( $search, &$query_vars ) {
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || empty($search) ) {
        return $search;
    }
    
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) return $search;
    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
    if ( sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_sku_for_admin', 999, 2 );
```